# How to fix wrong pylance warning for pandas code in my vscode project?

Tags: pandas, visual-studio-code, static-analysis, python-typing, pylance

I'm trying to keep my Python project in VSCode free of PyLance warnings. Unfortunately it looks like there's no complete typing information for Pandas objects. Here is a simple example:

This simple working code for creating a pandas Timestamp object:

```
ts = pd.Timestamp("2019-03-31 00:00:00")
```

will give me the warning:

```
Arguments missing for parameters "month", "day"
```

It looks like that the typing information for the Timestamp object does not know that it supports a string as parameter.

I know that I can turn it off with the `# type:ignore` comment:

```
ts = pd.Timestamp("2019-03-31 00:00:00")),  # type: ignore
```

I want to educate my interns to solve all typing warnings, so this is bad practice.

How can I configure these extra typing information and commit it to my project? Can I add my own type stubs to my project?

Comment: Looks like Pylance uses a set of [type stubs](https://github.com/microsoft/python-type-stubs) to typecheck pandas code. It appears to be defined [here](https://github.com/microsoft/python-type-stubs/blob/4033be7af6d8fe625e1c7cbf26caeb654ad716b0/pandas/_libs/tslibs/__init__.pyi#L154). There's a comment with it: "For the next two, inheriting from the datetime objects is not strictly accurate, as these are replacements for those, not derivations of those. Nontheless, using them as base classes saves us some effort here for now." Not 100% sure, but it looks promising.

Comment: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/39813 https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/28142 related gh issues